# Update datetime field randomly according known datetime

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, random

Is it possible to query a database row and according from one field (DATETIME) randomly add 1-3 days(better business days) into another field in the same row?

So query for known DATETIME field from which need to get time and then randomly add 1-3 days:

```
SELECT complete_date 
FROM training 
WHERE tr_id = 18;
```

AND query for the field which is needed to be updated..

```
UPDATE training 
SET finalized = (rand + (1-3 days)) 
WHERE tr_id = 18
```

MySQL Workbench software.

Comment: random numbers are database specific -- what database software are you using?

Comment: if i understand correctly, currently you have a field complete date.
and you want to have another field finalised which will be 1-3 days after the completed date. am i right?

Comment: Yes You are right. And database is in tag MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need the INTERVAL keyword.

```
UPDATE training SET finalized = complete_date + INTERVAL FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 3)) DAY
```

Adding working days is a little more difficult. Have a look at this [stored procedue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731260/mysql-function-to-add-a-number-of-working-days-to-a-datetime#17731608).

Comment: Great, its that I wanted thank you, but is it possible to add only bussiness days, so days which are not saturdays and sundays? :)

Comment: Adding working days is a little more difficult. Have a look at this [stored procedue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17731260/mysql-function-to-add-a-number-of-working-days-to-a-datetime#17731608).

Answer (score 0):

```
create table training (tr_id integer, complete_date datetime, finalized datetime);

insert into training values(18, NOW(), null);
insert into training values(18, NOW(), null);
insert into training values(18, NOW(), null);
insert into training values(18, NOW(), null);

update training set finalized = DATE_ADD(complete_date, Interval RAND()*24*3 HOUR) where tr_id = 18;
```

So you should add random number to some date to get new "random date".
In my example I add random from 0 to 72 hours to initial date 'complete_date', you can use SECONDS or what you need.

It is not so easy to support only buisness days. (what about NY hollidays in Russia - around 10 days :)